# Where is my MPI job running?

Tags: desktop-application, mpi

I am running an MPI job on a desktop that has 8 processors (2 quads, actually).  Because of some poor performance I am seeing, I suspect that two or more of my processes are running on the same processor.  This is not a cluster system; all the processors have the same name.  Is there any way for me to tell where exactly my processes are all running?  Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the CPU scheduler your OS is using. MPI itself usually does not bind processes to specific CPU. In case of linux, you can monitor load for each CPU core with `htop`

Comment: Thanks!  htop isn't anywhere in my PATH.  Could you tell me where it is usually installed?  Thanks.   Scratch that.  Got it.  Thanks.

Comment: On my system, it's `/usr/bin/htop`, but thare is a chance it is simply not installed. You can also run `top` and press `1` to toggel detailed statistics for each CPU. Or call `ps -p <PID> -o pid,psr,pcpu`, replacing <PID> with PID of one of your processes; the PSR column will contain the number of core process is assigned to, and PCPU is how much time of this core it uses (in %)

Comment: On a system like this (with 2 sockets), cache line contention and resulting inter-socket traffic can result in very poor performance indeed.  Which MPI implementation are you using?  Have you tried profiling to find out where is the application spending most time?  Also try pinning processes to cores and see if it helps.

Comment: @Greg Inozemtsev: I am using mpich.  Yeah, I know it's old, but it is what ships with PGI.  Haven't tried profiling.  Was hoping to not have to download or install any more software for a while.  Does mpich have its own profiling utility?  Showing my ignorance here, I guess.  Am trying the pinning.  Will see how it goes.  Thanks.

Comment: If that build of MPICH includes MPE, then I think logging is built in, and you can compile with `mpicc -mpilog` (or mpif77).  When you the program, it will automatically produce a log of all MPI calls.  The log can be viewed with [Jumpshot](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/perfvis), which may already be installed.  For more detailed profiling, you can use the PGPROF tool which is included in PGI.  Here's a quick [tutorial](http://www.bu.edu/tech/research/computation/linux-cluster/katana-cluster/programming/pgprof_tutorial/).

Comment: @Greg Inozemtsev: Thanks for the info.  Also, process pinning seems to have produced a small but statistically significant improvement in performance.  So process placement seems to be a part of the story, but there must be other big stuff going on as well.

Comment: You could be exceeding the available memory bandwidth at a certain point. How does your code scale with the number of MPI processes?

Comment: @Hristo Iliev: It scales horribly.  4 procs gets me a speed up of 30% over 1 proc.

Comment: Try process binding. Then think of doing performance analysis of the code. If it is memory bound and the memory bandwidth is saturated by a small number of processes, you won't get any speedup with more processes.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev: I'm not above showing my ignorance.  By "process binding", do you mean the same thing that Greg Inozemtsev meant by "pinning"?  Did that already with taskset.  It gave a real but small boost to performance.

Comment: Yes, binding and pinning are two different ways to say the same. If it doesn't improve things much, then your code is either memory bound (is it vectorised with SSE or AVX by the compiler?) or its serial part is too big (communication overhead counts towards it) and speedup is severely limited by [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Comment: @Hristo Iliev: No SSE.  That's another problem with the code.  I have inherited this thing, by the way, and not written it.  It is kind of old, and the originator, who had some bad programming habits, was relying on some behavior that gets broken when SSE come into play.